# Is the Sharepoint logo necessary?

Tags: sharepoint

My company uses Sharepoint. The Sharepoint logo is at the top and larger than our companies logo. Does MS require this? I can not get the IT guys to change the font or order of the logos. what gives?

Comment: If you say what version of Sharepoint you are using someone may tell you how to change the logo.

Answer (score 3):

Sharepoint is just a framework, you can change whatever you want on the pages. There are no required parts (that have to be displayed..). If the IT guys wont change it, they're either refusing or don't know how.